# truffle migrate --network kovan >> ProviderError: VM Exception while processing transaction: revert

Tags: truffle, truffle-migration, truffle-deployment, kovan, truffle-hdwallet-provider

I am a beginner.
I can deploy to a private network but I can not deploy to a public network.
I need a Deploy to the kovan test network. please help me.

```
>truffle init

>npm install truffle-hdwallet-provider
```

***** Token.sol *****

```
pragma solidity >=0.4.25 <0.6.0;

contract Token {

    mapping (address => uint256) public balanceOf;

    constructor(uint256 initialSupply) public {
        balanceOf[msg.sender] = initialSupply;
    }

    function transfer(address _from, address _to, uint256 _value) public returns (bool success) {
        require(balanceOf[_from] >= _value);                // Check if the sender has enough
        require(balanceOf[_to] + _value >= balanceOf[_to]); // Check for overflows
        balanceOf[_from] -= _value;
        balanceOf[_to] += _value;
        return true;
    }
}
```

***** Shop.sol *****

```
pragma solidity >=0.4.25 <0.6.0;

import "./Token.sol";

contract Shop {

    struct Product {

        string name;

        string imgPath;

        uint256 price;

        uint256 quantity;

        address seller;
    }
    event AddedProduct(uint256 pid, address seller, uint256 timestamp);
    event BuyProduct(uint256 pid, address buyer, uint256 timestamp);
    mapping (uint256 => Product) products;
    mapping (uint256 => address[]) buying;
    Token token;

    constructor (address _tokenAddress) public {
        token = Token(_tokenAddress);
    }

    function addProduct(
        uint256 _pid,
        string memory _name,
        uint256 _price,
        uint256 _quantity,
        string memory _imgPath,
        uint256 timestamp
    ) public {
        products[_pid] = Product({
            name: _name,
            imgPath: _imgPath,
            price: _price,
            quantity: _quantity,
            seller: msg.sender
        });
        emit AddedProduct(_pid, msg.sender, timestamp);
    }

    function getProduct(uint256 _pid) public view returns (string memory, uint256, uint256, string memory, address) {
        Product memory product = products[_pid];
        return (product.name, product.price, product.quantity, product.imgPath, product.seller);
    }

    function buyProduct(uint256 _pid, uint256 _timestamp) public {
        require(products[_pid].quantity > 0, "Product is sold out");

        Product storage product = products[_pid];
        address _buyer = msg.sender;
        token.transfer(_buyer, product.seller, product.price);

        product.quantity -= 1;

        buying[_pid].push(_buyer);
        emit BuyProduct(_pid, _buyer, _timestamp);
    }
}
```

***** 2_deploy_contracts.js *****

```
const Token = artifacts.require('./Token.sol');
const Shop = artifacts.require('./Shop.sol');

module.exports = function(deployer, network , accounts) {

  deployer

    .deploy(Token, 1000000, {from: accounts[0]})

    .then(async () => {

      const tokenContract = await Token.deployed();
      return deployer.deploy(Shop, tokenContract.address);
    })
    .then(async () => {
      const token = await Token.deployed();
      const coinbase = accounts[0];
      const value = 50000;
      await token.transfer(coinbase, accounts[1], value);
    });
};
```

***** truffle-config.js *****

```
const HDWalletProvider = require('truffle-hdwallet-provider');

const mnemonic = ".....";

module.exports = {

  networks: {

    development: {
      host: "127.0.0.1",
      port: 7545,
      network_id: "*"
    },

    kovan: {
      provider: function() {
        return new HDWalletProvider(mnemonic, "https://kovan.infura.io/v3/.....")
      },
      network_id: 42,
      skipDryRun: true
    },
},

}
```

```
>truffle migrate --network kovan

Error: Error: ProviderError: VM Exception while processing transaction: revert 

at Object.run (C:\Users\WINDOWS\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\truffle\build\webpack:\packages\truffle-migrate\index.js:92:1) 

at processTicksAndRejections (internal/process/next_tick.js:81:5) 

Truffle v5.0.33 (core: 5.0.33) Node v11.12.0 

PS D:\Blockchain Dev\t2>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You want to send tokens to `accounts[1]` address, however, `HDWalletProvider` by default unlocks only one address. You should add additional arguments to `HDWalletProvider` call. `HDWalletProvider(mnemonic, "your_infura_link", 0, 2)`. The third argument is the default address to send transactions from (starting from zero). The 4th argument is the total amount of unlocked addresses. More info: [here](https://github.com/trufflesuite/truffle/tree/develop/packages/hdwallet-provider#general-usage).

Comment: I tried as you said but still got the same error.

Comment: You should add `{from: accounts[0]}` to `deployer.deploy()` function call (as third argument) to explicitly use `account[0]` to deploy the contract from. (Don't understand actually why truffle uses another address).

Comment: return deployer.deploy(Shop, tokenContract.address, accounts[0]);

Comment: Error: Error: Error:  *** Deployment Failed *** 
"Shop" -- Invalid number of parameters for "undefined". Got 2 expected 1!

Comment: Try adding `skipDryRun: true,` to your network config in `truffle-config.js`. The problem appears when Truffle simulating deployment - accounts[0] is not the account that unlocked in the HDWalletProvider, but a simulated one. And in script you try to send tokens from accounts[0], but it does not have any. In real network everything should be ok. And if you do not want to skip simulation, try `deployer.deploy(Token, 1000000, { from: accounts[0] })`

Comment: I added {from: accounts [0]} in deployer.deploy (Token, 1000000) and added skipDryRun: true to truffle-config.js. Still error. NEW ERROR : https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/questions/75889/error-migrate-kovan