# Error : migrate kovan

Tags: dapp-development, truffle-migration, truffle-deployment, kovan, truffle-hdwallet-provider

From : [truffle migrate --network kovan >> ProviderError: VM Exception while processing transaction: revert](https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/questions/74827/truffle-migrate-network-kovan-providererror-vm-exception-while-processing)

```
>truffle migrate --reset --network kovan

Warning: Both truffle-config.js and truffle.js were found. Using truffle-config.js.

Compiling your contracts...
===========================
> Compiling .\contracts\Token.sol
> Artifacts written to D:\Blockchain Dev\t2\build\contracts
> Compiled successfully using:
   - solc: 0.5.8+commit.23d335f2.Emscripten.clang

Warning: Both truffle-config.js and truffle.js were found. Using truffle-config.js.

Migrations dry-run (simulation)
===============================
> Network name:    'kovan-fork'
> Network id:      42
> Block gas limit: 0x7a1200


1_initial_migration.js
======================

   Replacing 'Migrations'
   ----------------------
   > block number:        13446679
   > block timestamp:     1568292923
   > account:             0x8cf9f3920726e671716Fe6c44821DC0b56035B8D
   > balance:             5.86826832679724222
   > gas used:            246393
   > gas price:           2 gwei
   > value sent:          0 ETH
   > total cost:          0.000492786 ETH

   -------------------------------------
   > Total cost:         0.000492786 ETH


2_deploy_smartcontract.js
=========================

   Deploying 'Token'
   -----------------
   > block number:        13446681
   > block timestamp:     1568292936
   > account:             0x7D163E973E31a7532dB7EfeeAaaE360FEBD48126
   > balance:             99.999477718
   > gas used:            261141
   > gas price:           2 gwei
   > value sent:          0 ETH
   > total cost:          0.000522282 ETH


   Deploying 'Shop'
   ----------------
   > block number:        13446682
   > block timestamp:     1568292946
   > account:             0x8cf9f3920726e671716Fe6c44821DC0b56035B8D
   > balance:             5.86661835279724222
   > gas used:            797964
   > gas price:           2 gwei
   > value sent:          0 ETH
   > total cost:          0.001595928 ETH

Error: Invalid JSON RPC response: ""
    at Object.InvalidResponse (D:\Blockchain Dev\t2\node_modules\truffle-hdwallet-provider\dist\webpack:\truffle-hdwallet-provider\Users\gnidan\src\work\truffle\node_modules\web3\node_modules\web3-core-helpers\src\errors.js:42:1)
    at t.InvalidResponse [as onreadystatechange] (D:\Blockchain Dev\t2\node_modules\truffle-hdwallet-provider\dist\webpack:\truffle-hdwallet-provider\Users\gnidan\src\work\truffle\node_modules\web3\node_modules\web3-providers-http\src\index.js:92:1)
    at t._a [as dispatchEvent] (D:\Blockchain Dev\t2\node_modules\truffle-hdwallet-provider\dist\webpack:\truffle-hdwallet-provider\Users\gnidan\src\work\truffle\node_modules\xhr2-cookies\dist\xml-http-request-event-target.js:27:61)
    at t.dispatchEvent [as _setReadyState] (D:\Blockchain Dev\t2\node_modules\truffle-hdwallet-provider\dist\webpack:\truffle-hdwallet-provider\Users\gnidan\src\work\truffle\node_modules\xhr2-cookies\dist\xml-http-request.js:208:1)
    at t._setReadyState [as _onHttpRequestError] (D:\Blockchain Dev\t2\node_modules\truffle-hdwallet-provider\dist\webpack:\truffle-hdwallet-provider\Users\gnidan\src\work\truffle\node_modules\xhr2-cookies\dist\xml-http-request.js:349:1)
    at ClientRequest._onHttpRequestError (D:\Blockchain Dev\t2\node_modules\truffle-hdwallet-provider\dist\webpack:\truffle-hdwallet-provider\Users\gnidan\src\work\truffle\node_modules\xhr2-cookies\dist\xml-http-request.js:252:47)
    at ClientRequest.emit (events.js:197:13)
    at TLSSocket.socketErrorListener (_http_client.js:397:9)
    at TLSSocket.emit (events.js:197:13)
    at emitErrorNT (internal/streams/destroy.js:91:8)
    at emitErrorAndCloseNT (internal/streams/destroy.js:59:3)
    at processTicksAndRejections (internal/process/next_tick.js:76:17)
   -------------------------------------
   > Total cost:          0.00211821 ETH


Summary
=======
> Total deployments:   3
> Final cost:          0.002610996 ETH

Warning: Both truffle-config.js and truffle.js were found. Using truffle-config.js.
Warning: Both truffle-config.js and truffle.js were found. Using truffle-config.js.

Starting migrations...
======================
> Network name:    'kovan'
> Network id:      42
> Block gas limit: 0x7a1200


1_initial_migration.js
======================

   Replacing 'Migrations'
   ----------------------
   > transaction hash:    0x71f1ecd87d73ac93b1a0b851cbec1ee14ea33f4c6e8d1f0337c5f2a735238565
   > Blocks: 1            Seconds: 5
   > contract address:    0x99B3B76E319A398B7f31C425Bf86bf3F9A00e1ef
   > block number:        13446694
   > block timestamp:     1568292972
   > account:             0x8cf9f3920726e671716Fe6c44821DC0b56035B8D
   > balance:             5.86353325279724222
   > gas used:            261393
   > gas price:           20 gwei
   > value sent:          0 ETH
   > total cost:          0.00522786 ETH


   > Saving migration to chain.
   > Saving artifacts
   -------------------------------------
   > Total cost:          0.00522786 ETH


2_deploy_smartcontract.js
=========================

   Deploying 'Token'
   -----------------
   > transaction hash:    0x6a66f4e346b295ae6a7b930049dcf2a78d1f60466acc28e06a2f6d382bdc2a21
   > Blocks: 2            Seconds: 5
   > contract address:    0x55eAe6a8AA8d78E76E23469D60fCA9D871acf737
   > block number:        13446699
   > block timestamp:     1568292992
   > account:             0x8cf9f3920726e671716Fe6c44821DC0b56035B8D
   > balance:             5.85716997279724222
   > gas used:            276141
   > gas price:           20 gwei
   > value sent:          0 ETH
   > total cost:          0.00552282 ETH


   Deploying 'Shop'
   ----------------
   > transaction hash:    0xcbc525179d836c872fcc4abf4554580bff9407a89f0b47b83494c6854d2f5b2b
   > Blocks: 1            Seconds: 5
   > contract address:    0x35599a6CA54496cfA5F6E57aCf7D59b0c27376A1
   > block number:        13446703
   > block timestamp:     1568293008
   > account:             0x8cf9f3920726e671716Fe6c44821DC0b56035B8D
   > balance:             5.84091069279724222
   > gas used:            812964
   > gas price:           20 gwei
   > value sent:          0 ETH
   > total cost:          0.01625928 ETH

Error: Error: Error: invalid address (arg="_to", coderType="address", value=undefined)
    at Object.run (C:\Users\WINDOWS\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\truffle\build\webpack:\packages\truffle-migrate\index.js:92:1)
    at processTicksAndRejections (internal/process/next_tick.js:81:5)

Truffle v5.0.33 (core: 5.0.33)

Node v11.12.0

PS D:\Blockchain Dev\t2>
```

Comment: The problem appears to be in a `migrations/2_deploy_smartcontract.js`. I'd recommend to try to narrow down the line that causes the problem and update the question with the results.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looks like the same problem as in [previous question](https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/questions/74827/truffle-migrate-network-kovan-providererror-vm-exception-while-processing). You should add two last arguments (0 and 2) to `HDWalletProvider(mnemonic, link, 0, 2)` cause now your accounts[1] is undefined, bcause it was not unlocked by the provider. You also can try to `console.log(accounts)` to check the number of unlocked accounts.

Also, I still see **Migrations dry-run (simulation)** - this means you haven't switched it off.

Comment: I can now migrate to kavan. Thank you very much, very much.